# How to test value in input using XPath

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, knockout.js

In my selenium tests I need to find input element with specific value.

UI is rendered by following code:

```
<div id="product-list">
  <!-- ko foreach: $data.productItems -->
    <div class="product-list-item">
      <input data-bind="value: $data.name">
    </div> 
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

My selenium tests uses following code to find input element with specific name:

```
By xpath = By.xpath(".//div[@id='product-list']//div[contains(@class, 'product-list-item')]/input[@value='Product Name']");
WebElement element = browser.getWebDriver().findElement(xpath);
```

The problem is that element is always null since the `input[value='Product Name]"` will always fail, because there is no "value" attribute in input. There is just property "value" which you can see via it e.g. "Developer Tools" in Chrome.

I have some example for investigating why "value" is not correctly processed.

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/5fye0bbx/5/)

Is there some advice how to find proper input element? Or at least explain how to handle value attribute vs value property?

EDIT1: fixed missing @ in `input[@value='Product Name']`

EDIT2: updated example

EDIT3: Isn't the issue caused by inability XPATH to access DOM properties and is only capable to process HTML (or any other XGML) tag structure and its attributes? Since the knockout pushes the real value into DOM properties only, it is then not reachable from XPATH.

Comment: The value attribute lets the browser set the initial value for the input,  so you don't want to try and select via that.   Use selenium to find all of the elements with class product-list-item and iterate through them to get the one that has the value you care about.   Or execute JavaScript to return the element with the desired value.  The first way is better in my opinion.

Comment: @BryanEuton Attribute value is for initial value only. That explains a lot, thanks. But iteration is not possible. I have only one shot with single xpath which has to return the node (if present).

Comment: getWebDriver() should have another method called findElements which takes the xpath selector

Comment: @BryanEuton I know, but it is not possilble from different reason. I really need specific xpath for single node. Iteration is not possible because the DOM may change before I process iteration item.

Comment: Try the following xpath. //div[@id='product-list']//div[contains(@class, 'product-list-item')]/input[@value='Product Name]"

Comment: You are missing @ symbol before value attribute

Answer (score -1):

The last part of your XPath is incorrect:

```
/input[value='Product Name']
```

This means you are searching for an `<input>` where it's `value` attribute equals `Product Name`.

You want to search for the `data-bind` attribute instead:

```
/input[@data-bind='value: Product Name']
```

---

After retrieving the `WebElement`, get the value (not the `value` attribute) of the `<input>`:

```
element.getAttribute("value")
```

Comment: [at]data-bind is special attribute which is used by knockout.js for binding data model to html element. There is plenty of same inputs which differs only by their value and I cannot iterate over them to pick the right one according to its value. That is why I need to use @value in xpath

Answer (score -1):

I guess, you made some typo or don't know if that was intentional. You can refer below code and see if that helps

```
    By xpath = By.xpath(".//div[@id='product-list']//div[contains(@class, 'product-list-item')]/input[@data-bind='value: Product Name']");
WebElement element = browser.getWebDriver().findElement(xpath);
element.getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: @data-bind is special attribute which is used by knockout.js for binding data model to html element. This is wrong way. And also element.getAttribute("value") is not a way forward. I don't need the value, I  just need to test it.